# IIS: Limit number of connections for one IP?

Tags: iis, ip

Is it possible to limit number of connections for one IP for IIS or Web site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing built into IIS to limit the number of connections on a per IP basis. IP's can be blocked or granted, but not throttled to connection limit.  You could write code the store the IP address based on server variables, then refuse connection, but that is beyond IIS.